# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{[a_ncos(nx)]^{(m)}+[b_nsin(nx)]^{(m)}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty{(|a_nn^m| + |b_nn^m|)}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Okay so here's the the problem:

> Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then, $\forall$ $m \in [1,k]$,
>   $$f^{(m)}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{[a_ncos(nx)]^{(m)}+[b_nsin(nx)]^{(m)}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty{(|a_nn^m| + |b_nn^m|)}$$

Now I'm not sure really sure how to approach this. A friend of mine asked me for some aid with this, saying to use the "Differentiation Theorem of a function" from Rudin's text. I really wasn't sure which Differentiation Theorem he was speaking of and trying to dig deeper, he said that's all he knew on the way to approach this. I tried looking at Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem but it seemed far too complicated for this problem. My friend supplied me with a Theorem and its corollary that lead to the proposition:

> **Theorem**: If $f$ is a periodic function with Fourier coefficients $a_n,b_n$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(|a_nn^k|+|b_nn^k|)$ converges for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f$ has continuous derivatives $f',f'',...,f^{(m)}$
>
> **Corollary**: Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. If $f$ is periodic, with Fourier coefficients $a_n,b_n$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(|a_n| + |b_n|)|n^k|}$ converges for some $k$, then $\forall$ $m \in [0,k]$ it follows that
>    $$f^{(m)}(x)=\frac{d^m}{dx^m}[a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty({a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)})] $$

The proposition clearly sets up an inequality between the Theorem and its Corollary. I'm just quite unsure where to go with this. If anyone could give a hand, my friend and I would be much obliged.

**EDIT****EDIT****EDIT**

Thanks to Michael Albanese, I think I've got the answer now. Here is my attempt at a formal proof

> **Proposition:** Prove $\forall$ $m \in [1,k]$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that 
>   $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx))) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty(|a_nn^m|+|b_nn^m|)$$
>
> ***Proof***
>
> Consider $\mathbb{Z_4}$, where we have equivalence classes $[0]_4,[1]_4,[2]_4,[3]_4$. Now observe that $\forall$ $m \in [1,k]$
>   $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(cos(nx))=\left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        n^mcos(nx)  & m\equiv [0]_4\\
>        -n^msin(nx)  & m\equiv [1]_4\\
>        -n^mcos(nx) &m\equiv [2]_4\\
>        n^msin(nx)  &m\equiv [3]_4
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>
> $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(sin(nx))=\left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        n^msin(nx)  & m\equiv [0]_4\\
>        n^mcos(nx)  & m\equiv [1]_4\\
>        -n^msin(nx) &m\equiv [2]_4\\
>        -n^mcos(nx)  &m\equiv [3]_4
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>
> Further,
>
> $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(cos(nx)) \leq \bigl|\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(cos(nx))\bigr|=\left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        |n^mcos(nx)|  & m\equiv [0]_4\\
>        |n^msin(nx)|  & m\equiv [1]_4\\
>        |n^mcos(nx)| &m\equiv [2]_4\\
>        |n^msin(nx)|  &m\equiv [3]_4
>      \end{array}
>    \right. $$
>   $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(sin(nx)) \leq \bigl|\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(sin(nx))\bigr|=\left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        |n^msin(nx)|  & m\equiv [0]_4\\
>        |n^mcos(nx)|  & m\equiv [1]_4\\
>        |n^msin(nx)| &m\equiv [2]_4\\
>        |n^mcos(nx)|  &m\equiv [3]_4
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>
> Recall now that $\bigl|cos(x)\bigr| \leq 1$ and $\bigl|sin(x)\bigr| \leq 1$ which extends to $nx$. Thus,
>
> $$\bigl|\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(cos(nx))\bigr| \leq \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        |n^m|  & m\equiv [0]_4\\
>        |n^m|  & m\equiv [1]_4\\
>        |n^m| &m\equiv [2]_4\\
>        |n^m|  &m\equiv [3]_4
>      \end{array}
>    \right. \equiv |n^m|$$
>   $$\bigl|\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(sin(nx))\bigr| \leq \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        |n^m|  & m\equiv [0]_4\\
>        |n^m|  & m\equiv [1]_4\\
>        |n^m| &m\equiv [2]_4\\
>        |n^m|  &m\equiv [3]_4
>      \end{array}
>    \right. \equiv |n^m|$$
>
> since for both $\bigl|\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(cos(nx))\bigr|$ and $\bigl|\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(sin(nx))\bigr|$, we see our last inequalities result in $|n^m|$ for $[0]_4,[1]_4,[2]_4,[3]_4$. Therefore, it follows that
>
> $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx))) 
> = \sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((cos(nx))+b_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((sin(nx)))$$ 
>   $$\leq \bigl|\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
> (a_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((cos(nx))+b_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((sin(nx))\bigr)|$$
>   $$\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 
> (\bigl|a_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((cos(nx))+|b_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((sin(nx))\bigr|)$$
>
> $$\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 
> (\bigl|a_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((cos(nx))\bigr|+\bigl|b_n\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((sin(nx))\bigr|)$$
>   $$\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty(|a_nn^m|+|b_nn^m|)$$
>
> $$\implies \frac{d^m}{dx^m}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx))) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty(|a_nn^m|+|b_nn^m|)$$ $$\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\cos(nx) = \begin{cases}
n^m\cos(nx) & m \equiv 0 \bmod 4\\
-n^m\sin(nx) & m \equiv 1 \bmod 4\\
-n^m\cos(nx) & m \equiv 2 \bmod 4\\
n^m\sin(nx) & m \equiv 3 \bmod 4.
\end{cases}$$

Now use the fact that $|\cos(nx)| \leq 1$ and $|\sin(nx)| \leq 1$.

Comment: Oh my. So then showing a similar thing for sin(nx), we can then successfully set up our inequality. So we don't need to make any reference to the "Differentiation Theorem of a function"?

Comment: No you don't. I have no idea what your friend meant by that.

Comment: Alright I finally finished typing up my proof in Latex. It's long, but if you're willing to check it, it'd be of much help to me to know that I was on the right the right path. I'm going to put it in the original post.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.