# Proof of Fourier series Theorem (k-continuous derivatives)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Here's the theorem:

> **Theorem**: If $f$ is periodic with Fourier coefficients $a_n,b_n$ and if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (|n^{k}a_n|+|n^{k}b_n|)$$ converges for some integer $k \geq 1$, then f has continuous derivatives $f',...,f^{(k)}$ whose Fourier series are differentiated series of $f$. $\blacksquare$

So we know that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)$ on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. What needs to be done next is proving that the derivative of our series $f$ converges uniformly on our interval. I know how to prove the inequality 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n(cos(nx))^{(h)}+b_n(sin(nx))^{(h)}] \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|n^{h}a_n|+|n^{h}b_n|) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|n^{k}a_n|+|n^{k}b_n|)$$ 
for all $ h \in [1,k]$ via the Weierstrass M-Test. Using induction, is it sufficient to show $f'$ is uniformly convergent and work my way up from there to the $f^{(k)}$ case, where assume the convergence of the $(k-1)^{th}$ derivative of our series to be equal to $f^{(k-1)}$? Will that ultimately show that $$f^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n(cos(nx))^{(k)}+b_n(sin(nx))^{(k)}]?$$

If this is the case (which I'm almost positive it is based on the way uniform convergence is defined), then here is my attempt at a proof of this. If anyone could tell me if I did this even remotely correctly, I would quite grateful!

> **Attempted proof**: Consider $$f(x)=a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)]$$ which is $2\pi$-periodic. Differentiating $f$, we obtain 
>   $$f'(x) \sim \frac{d}{dx}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)]).$$
>   Recalling that $a_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)cos(nx)dx$ and $b_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)sin(nx)dx$, it using integration by parts that
>   $$a_n'=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f'(x)cos(nx)dx=nb_n$$ and $$b_n'=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f'(x)sin(nx)dx=-na_n$$ 
>   $$\implies f'(x) \sim \frac{d}{dx}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)])$$
>   $$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty [-na_nsin(nx)+nb_ncos(nx)]$$ 
>   $$\equiv \sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n\frac{d}{dx}(cos(nx))+b_n\frac{d}{dx}(sin(nx))].$$
>   Let's show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty [-na_nsin(nx)+nb_ncos(nx)]$ is uniformly convergent on $[-\pi,\pi]$, which will show that that our differentiated Fourier series converges to $f'$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Recall that $|cos(x)| \leq 1$ which extends to $|cos(nx)| \leq 1$ and $|sin(x)| \leq 1$ which extends to $|sin(nx)| \leq 1$. Thus,
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty [-na_nsin(nx)+nb_ncos(nx)]$$ 
>   $$\leq |\sum_{n=1}^\infty [-na_nsin(nx)+nb_ncos(nx)]|$$ 
>   $$\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |-na_nsin(nx)+nb_ncos(nx)|$$ 
>   $$\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty [|-na_nsin(nx)|+|nb_ncos(nx)|]$$
>   $$\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|na_n|+|nb_n|)$$
>   $$ \equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty (|n^1a_n|+|n^1b_n|)]$$
>   so we see our series is uniformly convergent on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by the Weierstrass M-Test, which implies that $f'$ represents our series on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and we have proved the case of $k=1$.
>
> Now suppose
>   $$f^{(k-1)}(x)=\frac{d^{(k-1)}}{dx^{(k-1)}}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)])$$
>   $$\equiv \sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n\frac{d^{(k-1)}}{dx^{(k-1)}}(cos(nx))+b_n\frac{d^{(k-1)}}{dx^{(k-1)}}(sin(nx))]$$
>   on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. We have currently have, since we don't know if the k-th derivative of $f$'s Fourier series converges to $f^{(k)}$,
>   $$f^{(k)} \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx^{(k)}}(cos(nx))+b_n\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx^{(k)}}(sin(nx))].$$ 
>   This part of the proof is actually proven in an older post on stackexchange, which I link here:
>
> "[Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{[a_ncos(nx)]^{(m)}+[b_nsin(nx)]^{(m)}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty{(|a_nn^m| + |b_nn^m|)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832479/proving-that-sum-n-1-inftya-ncosnxmb-nsinnxm-leq-sum/832487#832487)"
>
> It follows, finally, that $$f^{(k)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx^{(k)}}(cos(nx))+b_n\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx^{(k)}}(sin(nx))]$$
>   on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, so by the Principle of Mathematical Induction, we see that $f$ has $k$-continuous derivatives given the conditions imposed.
>   $$\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct but so wordy... How about this:

1. There is a standard theorem in real analysis: if $\sum f_n'$ converges uniformly on some interval $I$ and $\sum f_n$ converges at some point of $I$, then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $I$, its sum $f$ is differentiable, and $f'=\sum f_n'$.
2. The hypotheses in 1 apply to $f_n(x)=a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx$, because of the estimate
   $$|f_n'(x)| = |-n a_n \sin nx + nb_n\cos nx| \le 
    | n a_n \sin nx| + |nb_n\cos nx|
   \\ \le |n a_n|+|n b_n|$$
   and the Weierstrass M-test.
3. The case $k=1$ has been proved. The general case follows by induction.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It's a relief to know that I was correct. I know it's quite long, I just wanted to make it as detailed as possible so as to avoid any potential holes in my logic. That theorem you posted is incredibly helpful. I actually just found in Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis, 3rd edition* along with a few other useful Theorems to strengthen the proof (by citing of course, as I have no intentions of increasing the length of this already monstrous proof).

Comment: In the morning, I will be attempting to write a shorter proof with your suggestions. My only fear is that the $f^{(k}) will still be quite lengthy. Oh well. We'll see what I work out

Comment: Okay so I figured out a way to make it shorter: basically leave out the derivation of how to get to $f'$, as well as leaving out the summations when doing the Weierstrass M-Test. I was curious about something, if you're still willing to answer any more of my questions. If we just have $f \sim \sum ...$ then is it okay to make the assumption that $f_n$ converges for at least one point on $[-\pi,\pi]$ or does there need to be more information? If you're not sure, no worries. Just thought I'd ask.

Comment: @SavageHenry  [Kolmogorov constructed](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/69795/147263) an $L^1$ function whose Fourier series  diverges everywhere.

Comment: LOL oh my. That doesn't seem too promising for the direction I was thinking of going...